# .Net Core 2 Logout() in _loginpartial.cshtml as link?

Tags: c#, razor, asp.net-core-2.0

inside the **_loginpartial.cshtml** which was created by default with **dotnet new razor -au Individual**:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity
@using Lifejoice.Web.Data
@inject SignInManager<ApplicationUser> SignInManager
@inject UserManager<ApplicationUser> UserManager

@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right2">
            <li class="nav-item"> 
                <a class="nav-link" asp-page="/Account/Manage/Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn nav-link">Log out</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
else
{
    <ul class="navbar-nav navbar-righwt">
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
        <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" asp-page="/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
    </ul>
}
```

Here the Logout function is bound to a button inside the form. Is it possible to get the Logout()-function working as link () instead of a button inside a form?

Comment: The reason why this isn't a link is to prevent cross domain GET requests to the `Logout` action. Form posts can't be sent cross-domain. If you want to provide a link that works with a GET request without exposing your users to the risk of a cross-domain logout, I would suggest implementing a one-time token in the query-string for each logout link that you publish. A bit of a pain.

Comment: Thanks for Information. So i have to Style the Button like a link or?

Comment: Yes. A button can be styled to visually behave the same as an anchor link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned before: The reason why this isn't a link is to prevent cross domain GET requests to the Logout action. Form posts can't be sent cross-domain. If you want to provide a link that works with a GET request without exposing your users to the risk of a cross-domain logout, I would suggest implementing a one-time token in the query-string for each logout link that you publish.